# Should I encrypt data in database?

Tags: php, mysql, encryption

I have a client, for which I'm going to do an Web application about patient care, managing patients, consults, history, calendars, everything about that basically.

The problem is that this is sensitive data, patient history and such.

The client insists on encrypting the data at the database level, but I think this is going to deteriorate the performance of the web app. ( But maybe I shouldn't be worried about this )

I've read the laws about data protection on health issues ( Portugal ), but isn't very specific about this ( I just questioned them about this, I'm waiting for their response ).

I've read the following [link](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/144128/how-to-separate-sensitive-data-in-databasemysql), but my question is different, should I encrypt the data in the database, or not.

One problem that I foresee in encrypting data, is that I'm going to need a key, this could be the user password, but we all know how user passwords are ( 12345 etc etc ), and generating a key I would have to store it somewhere, this means that the programmer, dba, whatever could have access to it, any thoughts on this?

Even adding an random salt to the user password isn't going to solve the problem since I can always access it, and therefore decrypt the data.

Comment: I'm more of a client-side dev, but I suspect encrypting everything would actually make the data less, not more secure if you're using the same key.

Comment: can you put the entire database on an encrypted volume and call it a day. Sure reads/writes will be slower, but you keep all advantage of RDMS (or whatever you are using), while the data on disk is in encrypted

Comment: That also means you wont be able to see data in mysql workbench? All the best for debugging.

Comment: Medical is a highly regulated industry. The professionals working there are use to having someone tell them what the rules are. This mindset tents to spill over onto IT projects. It's not really a security issue. It's a cultural issue. The cost of doing business in the medical field.

Comment: A hospital in Britain was [fined over £300,000](http://www.ico.gov.uk/news/events/~/media/documents/library/Corporate/Research_and_reports/ico_presentation_20120920_BYOD_and_CMPs_Michele_Harmer.ashx) because disk drives  went astray containing unencrypted databases. Health information is very sensitive.

Comment: The user is going to log on with their password and then have access to the data, so the data is no more secure than the user's password no matter what method you use to get from password to key. You should refuse to allow the user to set their password to 12345 with an entropy checker which takes into account simple patterns (e.g. port zxcvbn).

Comment: This is a legal question, not a programming question. Consult a lawyer.

Comment: As far as security is concerned, programmer should only have to worry about establishing a username/password for client, username/password for application.  Explain how to change the password to the client and let *them* manage their own database.  If the data must be protected, hire a security guru.

Comment: Let me tell you about medical data, short form, for the layman: Encrypt the damn data. Believe you me: Your client's lawyers are waaay more likely to be correct about this than you unless you're a lawyer yourself (IN which case, why ask us?)

Comment: @medivh Lawyer advice regarding database design and computer security is probably worthless.

Comment: @PeterTaylor If the password is tested "server side" and that includes tested in a SIM card, or tested in a "secure" processor in a phone, you can have protections against systematic testing of thousands of combinations. You can slow down a lot after 5 attempts, you can add a lock out after one hundred... (although that creates other issues) If the password is used to generate an encryption key, then there is inherently no limit on the number that can be tried. Remember the FBI vs. Apple issue on that iPhone used by a terrorist had to do with that limitation on the number of attempts.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would personally check the laws on this.  If the data needs to be encrypted, then it needs to be encrypted.

If you don't receive any guidance though, I would aim to protect the link between the patient, and their data.  I.e. you most likely have a `PatientID` that's used in tables throughout the database.  `PatientID` does not identify a patient, only the patient's medical history etc...  However, to identify the `PatientID` as Joe Bloggs living at Rua de São Bernardo Lisbon, I'd keep this in a separate DB if I can.  Use TDE for the patient's personal details and consider encrypting it on-top of that using keys in your web application.

Whilst theft of that medical data without the means to identify the patients will be extremely embarrassing, it is unlikely to be anything beyond that.  There are literally [online competitions](http://www.heritagehealthprize.com/c/hhp) that use this anonymised medical data.

With the separation of the medical data from the patient's personal details.  Use a robust set of roles to limit staff to only what they need.  With the exception of medical staff that require to deal with the patient directly (front line nurses & doctors), no one should have access to both.  Receptionists only need Patient's personal details, lab staff only need the medical record and PatientID, surgical nurses only currently medical condition and first name.

When you've identified each set of roles, aim to not only implement them in your web application, but also in the database as well as an extra layer of security.

Comment: IANAL, but IMO laymen should not "check the laws" when the possible liability is large.  They should consult an attorney.

Comment: i go with this approach as true answer.. medical records that is not linked to patients nor doctor is meaningless and unusable even for statistical analysis as it has no reference nor prove that its not made up.

Answer (score 14):

Yes, you should encrypt the database.

Basic encryption for stored data ("data at rest") is a Generally Accepted Security Principle, and is probably mandated by law if your country has laws that protect personal or health information.

We're using SQL Server 2008, so we use Microsoft's TDE; there may be some third-party solution for MySQL or perhaps just a general volume encryption approach (such as TrueCrypt) would work (although I'd want to have something that has been certified for use with a database).

If done properly, the performance hit should be small.

By the way, the link you mentioned (regarding the separation of sensitive information) is something that you should consider on top of the basic database encryption.

EDIT: The encryption mentioned above would encrypt the volume.  If someone were to steal the hard drive, they'd find the data encrypted.  However, if someone were to run queries on the database, they'd see the unencrypted data (that's why I mentioned the separation of information, even though the OP didn't want to discuss this).

Note that this recommendation is meant as the minimum that you should do.  If you want legal advice, then of course you'll need to look elsewhere.  If you want a more thorough discussion of writing secure code, I would starting with the book [Writing Secure Code](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/book.aspx?id=5957&locale=en-us).

Comment: I am not sure if this is the case. The question is not about encrypting the database, but about encrypting the data in the database. That means the data in sql queries will be encrypted.

Comment: The performance hit should be small? Searching on data will be SLOW. The entire concept of indexing does not work when data is encrypted. It will require a full-table scan.

Comment: @mike The approach above would encrypt the volume and would not impact indexing etc.

Comment: IMO you need more expertise than you can get here.  IANAL, but I think your client has pretty high exposure if this data is compromised.

Answer (score 11):

Before deciding on such security matters, you should assess the threat model. Without an idea what you're defending against, any measures you take are likely to be of little value.

Now, there are a few things you could worry about in this context:

- Attackers gaining physical access to your data (e.g., breaking into the datacenter, stealing backup tapes, etc.)
- Attackers gaining read access to your raw database
- Attackers compromising your application, e.g. through SQL injection, buffer overruns, etc.

For the first scenario, storing the database and all backups on encrypted volumes should work, provided the server is headless - stealing the server or the tapes would then require breaking the disk-level encryption.

For the second scenario, encrypting database data does help, but only if you don't store the required keys or passphrases anywhere.

In the third scenario, everything depends on the context in which the attack happens: if it is, for example, an XSS or CSRF attack, then an attacker can do anything the legitimate user can, and encrypting your data doesn't help at all.

You threat model, thus, is an attacker who gains read access to the raw database, either by finding the login credentials and managing to log into the database server from outside, or by gaining root access to the database server. A typical path is to first gain shell access on the web server; from there, an attacker can then read the access credentials from the configuration file and connect to the database.

An additional consideration is where you keep the keys and passphrases, especially if you're using a platform with a stateless execution model such as PHP. Ideally, you have the customer type their passphrase when required, and keep it only in memory, or even better, do the decryption client-side (but this is not often feasible). On a stateless platform, state is usually carried along using sessions, memcache, databases, or flat files; but all these are far more vulnerable than keeping state in a stateful web application's own memory. Avoiding this is a chicken-and-egg problem, because if you encrypt the state before persisting it, you just created another secret that you have to remember safely. Remembering the passphrase on the client and sending it along with each request that needs it may be the least horrible solution then; the client is still vulnerable if you have any XSS leaks, and you need to take the usual precautions (serve only https, set all cookies to httponly and secure, etc.), but those are issues you have anyway.

Comment: +1: without a threat model, you are most likely locking the front door but leaving the back door wide open.

Answer (score 8):

Ignoring for a moment what the client is asking for, and whatever the laws are...

No, you probably should not encrypt the data.  If you do, you will not be able to easily search it.  For example, how would you search for a last name `like 'Smith%'` if every name entry is encrypted?  How would you graph a patient's blood pressure over time if you cant  `select .... from.... where patient_id = N`?

You should, obviously, make sure the server is properly secured, the network connection is secured, and that the user interface is properly secured (including session timeouts so users cant walk away leaving access to anyone who uses their computer).  You also may want to encrypt database backups.  And physically secure the room the server is located in.  But I would not encrypt the live data.

**Clarification:** This is assuming what the OP was asking about is actually encrypting the data *in* the database.  Not the file system the database resides on.

Comment: totally agree, yet LAWS doesn't :(

Comment: Well you could `AES_DESCRYPT('') LIKE 'Smith%'` albeit incredibly slow. Or you could get intense and make an inverted index with salted hashes

Answer (score 1):

If you develop the web application carefully using an effective MVC framework like CakePHP. Zend or Rails, then you should be able to enable/disable encryption at the data Modal level.

CakePHP for example has a few examples of Behaviors for Modal's that encrypt data. Making the process transparent to the Controllers and Views.

Ignoring issues about indexing and other technical database issues when doing this. It should be possible to have this as a configurable option.

Additionally, I would turn encryption on at either a later time or only on the production server. Encrypted data is difficult to debug and work with while developing, and can only be done on certain columns.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should encrypt the database.

Since this is personal and sensitive information, I definitely believe it should.

From the password, you can derive an encryption key which you only store for the session. That way, it isn't stored anywhere and nobody (including DBAs) can know it since nobody can know the password either. Anyone attempting to view the DB directly will be looking at gibberish. The only way to corrupt this is via session hijacking but I'm assuming here that sessions are secure as well.

Comment: People very often forget their passwords... then what?

Answer (score -1):

I ask myself why does the client ask you to encrypt the DB?
If he would ask you to protect the data I would agree, but he already has a implicit implementation in mind. So as long he doesn't know exactly what he is talking about he is just throwing buzzwords from my point of view.

I also find it very useless to encrypt the DB, because I am convinced that literally *every* major DBMS takes security into account appropriatly and probably better than you could.
In order to acces the DB through the DBMS you would need credentials. In case of a encrypted DB you would need those credentials aswell, and to decrypt the data you would need those credentials you already seem to have.

Following this mindset I propose to let the DBMS handle security, and put efforts in protecting credentials all the way from user input to db access, may also enforce strong passwords and periodical change.

Comment: ...every major DBMS takes securityinto account... [except when they don't](http://www.computerweekly.com/news/2240239540/US-health-insurer-Anthem-hacked-exposing-up-to-80-million-records).

Comment: First question I would have to ask is _how_ did they do that and how could the damage be prevented by encrypting the db. I just scanned quickly through this article, but got the impression that they were in possession of credentials.

Comment: Exactly -- DB Credentials can and do get compromised. The challenge is to design the system so that even when unauthorized users get access to the credentials, they still need additional encryption keys to be able to access sensitive data. For health information, this is even more complicated. Not everyone with access to the DB credentials should be able to access sensitive data. For instance DBA should not be able to read patient data in clear text. The only people that should be able to read this data are the patients and their providers.